# RequireJS does not accept URL`s in the config`s paths declaration

Tags: requirejs, async.js

I want to inject google this way that I can inject my own google mock in the runner.js for unit testing where I do not want http calls.

```
 paths: {
        lib: 'lib',        
        async: 'lib/async',
        google: 'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'
    },

define(['google'], function(google) {

});
```

google is always undefined.

When I use the define like that it works:

```
define(['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'], function(google) {

    });
```

But I can not use it that way because then goodle is hardcoded as string in the production code. That way I can not inject my own google mock in the unit test in the runner.js path definition...

Why does the first way not work?

Answer (score 0):

Google libraries do not implement module pattern. They expose all functionality to global google variable. In you mock library just mock everything on a globally accessible google variable. Workaround would be to include shim configuration so that when loaded, RequireJS knows what to pass to you module:

```
requirejs.config({
    // ...
    shim: {
        'google': {
            exports: 'google'
        },
    }
});
```

In sample above you are saying that when google module loads, pass global window.google variable as a module reference to your module.